# Fixes positions for nodes in r igraph?

Tags: r, nodes, igraph, fixed

Suppose we want to visualise a network like the one below

```
library(igraph)
a<- cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),
c(2,4,1,2,2))
b<- graph.edgelist(a, directed=FALSE)
```

Is there any way to keep the nodes in the ***same position*** apart from setting the coords by hand?? For example, can we edit the graph with ***tkplot*** and save the layout so that it remains the same no matter how many times we run the code? By using the function ***tkplot.getcoords***, I manage to save the layout only once. Is repeatablility possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Considering `tkp <- tkplot(b); coords <- tkplot.getcoords(tkp)`, you can backup the variable `coords`. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to set a seed with `set.seed`:

```
library(igraph)
a<- cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),
c(2,4,1,2,2))
b<- graph.edgelist(a, directed=FALSE)

set.seed(123)
plot(b)
```

And you'll get this each time you run the code:

[image]